# Как правильно использовать классы и модели в ООП?

Tags: php, ооп

Необходимо создать какой-либо новый функционал, который берет данные из БД и выводит их куда-то. Для этого создаю контроллер и модели, которые вызываю в контроллере, класс не создаю.
Вопрос - правильно ли я делаю, или в контроллере надо подключать класс, а в классе уже работать с моделями? Есть ли какие-то базовые принципы на этот счет?

Comment: Поизучайте php-фреймворки, посмотрите как в них принято делать

Comment: @andreymal плохая рекомендация. в том же yii2 все почти всегда (кто неопытен)  пихают всё в контроллер, либо модель. А по сути, можно следовать DDD (не берём в учёт мелкие бложики... хотя их тоже можно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это проблема не фреймворка, а неопытных :) Я надеюсь, в документациях всё-таки описаны best practices

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос очень простой.
Если вы умеете писать классы, то пишите. Если не умеете - не пишите. К моделям, контроллерам и функционалу это все не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @andreymal что-то не встречал ни одного фреймворка)) разве что symfony сразу по DDD сделано (ЕМНИП)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, laminas (ex zend framework)